# Broadcast coding from RStudio to the world with livecode package

Tags: r, http, webserver, port

`livecode` is a R package for broadcasting code for live code demonstrations. I would like to use it for teaching R in online classrooms. The package can be installed from github and runs excellent on my computer and the result is very promising. Once installed from github:

```
remotes::install_github("rundel/livecode")
library(livecode)
```

You can start your web server via `server = livecode::serve_file()`. Next your browser pops up and shows you a syntax-hightlighted live broadcast of your coding. A benefit in comparison to a screenshare of code is that this broadcast delivers plain text which is scalable from the recipient. I tested it on my phone, worked great. No more scaling of RStudio in order to make people see your code. Furthermore text (the script) can be saved from browser.

[image]

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/livecode-broadcast-your-live-coding-sessions-from-and-to-rstudio/

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to configure my private work environment such that this broadcast can be received from outside my local network. `serve_file` can specify an ip and port. I tried to set it to my computer ip (found via ipconfig) and open port 80 (for http) in my router.

Can anybody support me in how to make a `livecode` broadcast to the global internet?

Comment: (1) Use a [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) solution that maps a hostname to the apparent IP of your work environment. (2) Configure your router(s) to forward one specific port from the public to your computer on a known port. Regardless of what port you use on your own computer, I urge you to *not* use port 80 for the public side, otherwise you are a lot more susceptible to spiders, crawlers, etc. (3) Investigate if your own computer firewall will block incoming requests, and fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you go a little bit more into detail? I registered a DDNS account. I put DDNS information in my router. How can I put things together? I mean, finally at some point the shared bitly link from the livecode package should work, right?

Comment: If your DDNS is named `marco.name`, then the outside world should be able to resolve `marco.name` to be the same IP as what you see at https://whatismyipaddress.com/. Once that is good, then if you configure your router to forward incoming traffic on port 6789 to be forwarded to your work computer on port 80, then your students should configure `http://marco.name:6789` and it should work. I don't know about the bitly link, but if your bitly link includes the ddns name and correct external port number, then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the package author and he suggested to follow this blogpost:

https://bitsandbricks.github.io/post/code-live-from-rstudio-and-share-it-with-the-world-in-real-time/

It suggests to use `ngrok`, a service that provides tunnels to localhost. This acutally worked for me for some seconds, killing my `livecode` package in the next moment. At the moment, I can no longer use `livecode` not even as a localhost. I assume this error may just be my fault. The blogpost provides an easy answer to my question.